# Route 53, Nginx, SSL, Redirect http to https and www to non-www

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, amazon-route53

I have spent several hours but not getting the required results. Not sure if it has to do with browser cache - for some reason in Firefox it works fine but not anywhere else. My settings are as follows:

```
Route 53:

example.com A   Simple  -   No  x.x.x.x
example.com AAAA    Simple  -   No  x:x:3:d0::x:x
www.example.com A   Simple  -   Yes  example.com.
www.example.com AAAA    Simple  -   Yes  example.com.
```

In essence I have created an Alias to redirect all www traffic to non-www in Route 53.

In NGINX I have created the blocks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com ;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    root /var/www/mydomain;
    index index.php;

}
```

I thought this process would make sense but I am getting no server response:

This site can’t be reached

The web page at https://www.example.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Ok I actually found the problem in the security headers being incorrect. For some reason Firefox ignores these, hence why it was working.. https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header

Comment: Nevertheless I would like to know whether this is the correct approach to redirect www traffic to non-www for an SSL domain..